# Using separated .js javascript file to print to document

Tags: javascript, html

JS:

```
document.getElementById("terminal_text").innerHTML = "hello";
```

HTML:

```
<p id="terminal_text"></p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js1.js"></script>
```

1st line inside js file.
2nd line and 3rd line(inside head) in html file.

I'm trying to use a javascript file to print to a paragraph tag using the ID and it's not printing. Any ideas? Thank you ! :)

Comment: *"2nd line and 3rd line(inside head) in html file"* You can't put `p` elements in `head`; or rather, if you do, it terminates `head` and starts `body` implicitly (since the `</head>` and `<body>` tags are both optional in some situations).

Comment: If line 3 comes before line 2 in the html file, this will happen as you are trying to get an ID that doesn't yet exist.  Put line 3 in the body *after* line 2.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Pretty sure the (inside head) is only applying to the script tag here

Comment: But I've put the javascript into the Head tag?

Comment: You might need to do some tutorials on developing a web page. The `<body>` is where your elements go, the `<head>` is for information about the page such as title, scripts that are attached, etc

Comment: Millerbr, I know where things go, Joseph has clarified that the script is the only thing that I've dropped into the head tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the script tag after your element in the body:

```
<body>
.. stuff

<p id="terminal_text"></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js1.js"></script>

.. more stuff
</body>
```

Comment: But what happens if I want to put more scripts that need to be run for other tags under that paragraph to be manipulated? thanks :)

Comment: @TingAli: Put them all at the end, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Just make sure that scripts that execute immediately are *after* all the tags they use.

Comment: It's a [long discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup) where to put `<script>` tags`

Answer (score 0):

You must place the `<script>` tag after the `<p>` tag, otherwise you `<p>` tag does not exist when your javascript code runs.

If you don't want to do this you can execute your code on the `load` event when your page is fully loaded:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  document.getElementById("terminal_text").innerHTML = "hello";
});
```